# XSS and SQL Injection threats found by AppScan Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, xss, sql-injection

So I have been given administration on a website that is basically a company conference room reservation system, it is connected to an access database for room details and vacancies. Problem is, AppScan source is showing a risk of XSS and SQL Injection. This is the complete function in where it is indicating the occurrence of these errors.

```
protected void btnReserve_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
                            {
                                            string start_slot, end_slot, event_desc, room_id, emp_nid;
                                            string[] date;
                                            start_slot = ddlStart.SelectedValue;
                                            end_slot = ddlEnd.SelectedValue;
                                            event_desc = txtEventDesc.Text;
                                            room_id = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["room_id"]);
  emp_nid = Regex.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"], @"^.*\\(.*)$", "$1").ToUpper();
                                            date = Request.QueryString["date"].Split('/');
                                            DateTime dt = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(date[2]),Convert.ToInt32(date[0]),Convert.ToInt32(date[1]));
  string sCmdCheckConflict = @"
      SELECT     count(*)
      FROM         t_msc_event
      WHERE     (event_date = #" +DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["date"]).ToString() + @"# )
      AND (room_id = " + room_id + @") AND
      (
      (" + start_slot + @" BETWEEN start_slot AND end_slot) OR
      (" + end_slot + @" BETWEEN start_slot AND end_slot) OR
      (start_slot BETWEEN " + start_slot + @" AND " + end_slot + @") OR
      (end_slot BETWEEN " + start_slot + @" AND " + end_slot + "))";
  OleDbCommand cmdConflictCounter = new OleDbCommand(sCmdCheckConflict, cn);
  int n;
  int event_id;

  try
  {
    cn.Open();
    n = (int) cmdConflictCounter.ExecuteScalar();
                                                            string Msg;
    if (n>0)
    {
      Msg = "<script language=javascript>alert('Chosen time is not possible due to a conflict.');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
      #region MS Access related region
      OleDbCommand cmdgetMaxId = new OleDbCommand("select max(event_id) from t_msc_event", cn);
      string sCmdInsert;
      OleDbCommand cmdInsertEvent = null;
      event_id = 0; bool success = false; int trials = 0;
      do
      {
          try
          {
            event_id = (int) cmdgetMaxId.ExecuteScalar() + 1;
          }
          catch
          {
            event_id = 0;
          }
          sCmdInsert = @"
                                        insert into t_msc_event (event_id,
                                        emp_nid, event_desc, event_date,
                                        start_slot, end_slot, room_id
                                        ) values (" + event_id + @",
                                        '" + Server.HtmlEncode(emp_nid) + "', '" + Server.HtmlEncode(event_desc.Replace("'", "''")) + "', #" + dt.ToShortDateString() + "#, " +
            start_slot + ", " + end_slot + ", " + room_id + ")";             
          cmdInsertEvent = new OleDbCommand(sCmdInsert, cn);
          cmdInsertEvent.ExecuteNonQuery();
          success = true;
      } while ((!success) && (trials <=5));

      OleDbDataAdapter daGetSlots = new OleDbDataAdapter("select slot_id, left(slot_desc,5) as slot_start, right(slot_desc,5) as slot_end from t_msc_slot order by slot_id", cn);
      DataTable dtSlotInfo = new DataTable();
      daGetSlots.Fill(dtSlotInfo);
      OleDbCommand cmdGetRoolTitle = new OleDbCommand("select room_title from t_msc_room where room_id=" + Server.HtmlEncode(room_id), cn);
      string room_title = (string) cmdGetRoolTitle.ExecuteScalar();
      string msg = "Dear " + emp_nid +
        ",<br><br>This is to confirm your reservation of " +
        room_title +
        " on " + dt.ToShortDateString() + " from " +
        dtSlotInfo.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(start_slot)]["slot_start"].ToString() + " to " +
        dtSlotInfo.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(end_slot)]["slot_end"].ToString() + "." +
        "<br><br>In case you want to cancel, go to " +
        "<a href='" + Regex.Replace(Request.Url.ToString(), @"^(.*)/.*\.aspx\?*.*$", "$1/MyReservations.aspx") + "'>" +
        "MS Conference Rooms Reservation -> MyReservatios</a>";
      #endregion
      string subject = "MS Conference Room Reservation Confirmation [id=" + event_id + "]";
      try
      {
        SendEmail(emp_nid, subject, msg);
        Msg = "<script language=javascript>alert('Room successfully reserved. You should receive a confirmation email shortly.'); if (opener) {opener.__doPostBack('" + Request.QueryString["btnGetScheduleID"].Replace("_","$") + "', '');} window.close();</script>";
      }
      catch
      {
        Msg = "<script language=javascript>alert('Room successfully reserved.'); if (opener) {opener.__doPostBack('" + Request.QueryString["btnGetScheduleID"].Replace("_","$") + "', '');} window.close();</script>";
      }
    }
    Response.Write(Msg);
  }
                                            catch (Exception x)
                                            {
    Response.Write(x.ToString());
                                                            string Msg;
                                                            Msg = "<script language=javascript>alert('Error: " + x.ToString() + "');</script>";
    Response.Write(Msg);
                                            }
                                            finally
                                            {
                                                            cn.Close();
                                            }
                            }
```

Sorry for having to show you the whole function as I have really no idea what I need to do here, this isn't my app.
what I did do is 1) Enable Request Validation in ASP.NET 2) encode user input by using Server.HtmlEncode(); but it is still reporting the same thing. Note that both start_slot and end_slot are DDLs so I thought I wouldn't need to encode/check them before sending. Would you please help me in modifying this code to neglect harmful user input? Thank you loads.

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? You could rewrite the code, create strored procedures in the database and call them instead of having SQL statements in code.

Comment: This code appends user input to SQL queries, so it is susceptible to SQL Injection. You can use sql parameters instead.

Comment: @Alex          Thanks for replying! Do you mean a query? as I'm using an access database not SQL, only using Ole DB as the connection.

Comment: @RachitGupta   Thanks for replying! but I used Server.HtmlEncode on the only input that is directly taken from the user, wouldn't this be sufficient to cleanse the data? all other fields are either Drop Down lists or just dates chosen from a table and filled automatically.

Comment: I don't have much experience in SQL, so i can't tell whether Html.Encode will be sufficient or not. Anyhow SQL parameters are always a better choice. Also if Html.encode is enough, the tool may not be intelligent enough. It may just be seeing an append and show the threat.

Comment: @RachitGupta   I thank you very much for replying dear, I understand that the tool might not be intelligent enough but due to company policy, all applications have to comply so my hands are tied. Anyhow, can you please tell me how I can use parameters instead of appending?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use parameterized SQL query is

```
string commandText = "UPDATE ProductDetails
                      SET ProductQuantity = @quantity WHERE ProductId = @productId";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productId", "P123");       
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", 10);
```

You can safely replace the "P123" with user provided input now.